# Rewrite Docusign methods in Springboot raised javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException

Tags: java, docusignapi

I downloaded the example code and write docusign utils myself, but it gets exception. I searched code but cannot find out why.

I want to write a test() method let others use this method in our system, they can get token by using this method. Then they could call api themselves. This is a just util method.

Here is my code.

```
public void test() throws IOException, ApiException {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add("signature");
    byte[] privateKeyBytes;
    FileSystemResource rsaPrivateKey = new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/private.key");
    privateKeyBytes = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(rsaPrivateKey.getInputStream());

    String baseUrl = "account-d.docusign.com";
    String clientId = "my-client-key";
    String guId = "my-guId";
    apiClient.setOAuthBasePath(baseUrl);
    OAuthToken oAuthToken;
    try {
        oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
                clientId,
                guId,
                scopes,
                privateKeyBytes,
                TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);
    } catch (IOException | ApiException e) {
// Special handling for consent_required
        String message = e.getMessage();
        String consent_url = "";
        String consent_scopes = String.join("%20", scopes) + "%20impersonation";
        if (message != null && message.contains("consent_required")) {
            consent_url = String.format("https://%s/oauth/auth?prompt=login&response_type=code&scope=%s" +
                            "&client_id=%s" +
                            "&redirect_uri=%s",
                    baseUrl,
                    consent_scopes,
                    clientId,
                    "http://localhost:8080/login%26type%3Djwt");
            System.err.println("\nC O N S E N T   R E Q U I R E D" +
                    "\nAsk the user who will be impersonated to run the following URL: " +
                    "\n" + consent_url +
                    "\n\nIt will ask the user to login and to approve access by your application." +
                    "\nAlternatively, an Administrator can use Organization Administration to" +
                    "\npre-approve one or more users.");

            throw new BadRequestException("consent_required");
        }

        throw new BadRequestException("consent_required");

    }
    apiClient.setAccessToken(oAuthToken.getAccessToken(), oAuthToken.getExpiresIn());
}
```

And, in *apiClient.requestJWTUserToken* method, it raised the exceptions below:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;

    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:609)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:608)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:327)
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken(ApiClient.java:916)
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the issue is with the private key bytes.
Note the simple code to read it from file:

```
 byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(prop.getProperty("rsaKeyFile")));
```

You did mention that JWT code you downloaded worked, so I suggest you use that first and modify it for your needs and each modification - test to ensure it didn't break it.

Also, please confirm `private.key` was not modified in any way from the original that was downloaded for you.